# Calculating mipmaps with compute shaders, has it been done?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, compute-shader

I'm manually generating mipmaps with compute shaders since I don't simply filter but do some calculations in there.

The straighforward approach is to, per texel of level 1, read its four corresponding texels in level 0, do the filtering, and then write the texel. do that for the whole level, and then repeat for the next level.

But there must be a faster way :) instead of reading level 0, writing level 1, and then reading level 1 again, writing level 2 etc. it's likely more efficient to e.g. read a tile of level 0, and then write all the values for the next few levels iteratively in the same dispatch call. This way, up to half of the reads could be saved.

my question is, has this been done already? i'm interested in a more detailed algorithm that has proven to be efficient.

Specifically, I'm implementing a pull-push algorithm that first computes those miplevels from largest to smallest. In a second step it then refines the miplevels, starting at the second-to-smallest one, either using the original texel or an interpolation of the four surrounding texels in the *coarser* miplevel. Efficient computation schemes for this i'd like to see as well, but couldn't find any through googling.

Comment: But doing this in one iteration would require you to read the resulting data for the neighbor invocation, and so on, which would become a synchronization nightmare.

Comment: @derhass: i was imagining something like processing a 64x64 tile with one work group, (iteratively, not one thread per texel), and then writing 32x32 texels to level 1 AND to shared memory, then compute 16x16 texels of level 2, and 8x8 to level 3. then either do another dispatch call or do it all the way down to 1x1, depending on what's more efficient. in any way, there shouldn't be any synchronization needed. for the second (push) phase, the work groups would read overlapping tiles of data, but still, there shouldn't be any synchronization necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't realizing that this is basically a parallel reduction with some constraints. For parallel reduction, there is a nice whitepaper from NVIDIA with lots of optimization strategies that also might apply here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

Also, i found an example implementation of downscaling with compute shaders here: https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/average-luminance-compute-shader/ although it's a bit outdated, he e.g. explicitly tried to vectorize instructions.